# How does division's numerator and denominator changes their place?

Tags: calculus

For example we have:

[image]

How does it equal to:

[image]

I know that

[image]

But in that shifting they have wroten that it equals to

[image]

Comment: The shifting you are referring to is nothing more than another way of re-expressing 1 - $\sqrt{5}$

Comment: Multiply $\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}$ by $\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{1+\sqrt 5}$ to get a difference of squares in the numerator.

Comment: Basically rationalize your numerator is what amWhy is saying.

Comment: Thank you both for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a rule that numerator and denominator can change places. $\frac{a-b\sqrt{c}}{d}\not=\pm\frac{d}{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ but a coincidence.The correct method to solve this type of questions is to multiply top and bottom by the conjugate in this case $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}$
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{1^2-5}{2(1+\sqrt{5})}=-\frac{4}{2(1+\sqrt{5})}=-\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a _coincidence_, I'd call it a _method_ for dealing with $a+b\sqrt{c}$ in the denominator.

Comment: @EthanBolker I guess I should've  worded my answer better,I was talking that in general $\frac{a-b\sqrt{c}}{d}\not=\pm\frac{d}{a+b\sqrt{c}}$  that numerator and denominator don't change places.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{A}{B} =\dfrac{C}{D}$$

can shift places to

$$ \dfrac{D}{B} =\dfrac{C}{A}$$

or

$$ \dfrac{A}{C} =\dfrac{B}{D}$$

all because cross products taken of numerator/denominator on opposite sides of $=$ sign

$$ {A}{B} ={C}{D}$$

remain quite the same.